# DDD:- How to organize Identity Access features in a solution?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, subdomain, bounded-contexts

Shall i put my identity access (Authentication and Authorization) in the shared kernel or create a separate bounded context called for example:- **IdentityAccess**

1. If i put my identity access in the shared kernel, then the shared kernel will be bloated. the shared kernel should contain basic contracts such as BaseEntity or BasicValueObject to ease the development process
2. If i choose to make the identity accesss in a different bounded context, then how the other bounded contexts will apply permissions

**keep in mind, the identity access will contain a lot of features like User Login and Permission Management like(Create Users, rules and Groups)**

Answer (score 2):

Identity access should NOT contain Permission management; those are business functions belonging in the separate context, see this pic from Martin Fowler: [image]

Instead of Customer and Product in your case it will be Permission/Role/User etc. that exist in both bounded contexts.

So you should have:

1. Context for authentication/authorization
2. Context for permission management
3. Business contexts.

Then you need to organise the code in such a way that user interaction always goes through (1) but in a way that is opaque to (2) and any number of (3).

Specifically, you should NOT worry about permissions in the business context because it should never be invokable if the user does not have appropriate permissions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why a separate context for authorization and another for permission management? Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: @Farax Not at all. Authentication is 'prove you are John' and Permission management is 'what is John allowed to do'.

The first part requires some kind of security mechanism and is best isolated completely separately from the rest of the app.

Comment: Authentication is separate, agreed. You mentioned Authorization (which should be what is John allowed to do" in 1 and then permission management as 2, which is again "what is john allowed to do". Is that correct?

Comment: @Farax you are correct, i have made a poor choice of words.

Comment: so in the case where you have a UseCase/endpoint getCustomers, which gets all the customers the authenitcated user can see. While you can verify the user is authorized to call the API, you don't know what the data returned to the user will be until you actually go and get it. Typically that means when you are accessing the database you'll need to be saying something like
`SELECT * from Customers WHERE tenantId = user.tenantId`
That is you can only view customers which are in the same tenant as your user. To me, this is permissions

Comment: @friartuck This is a pretty old answer and my thinking has evolved somewhat since I posted it, but basically under that DDD paradigm the permission means `permission to call API`. You could define a separate `permission` as in `permission to see certain data` but that a) has no reference in the authentication context; b) is essentially a set of business logic that you should implement as an overarching business rule (such that if a dev accidentally forgets that `WHERE` clause you posted the user is never returned all the data.